# Getting the event target is not possible with trigger()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone help me telling why I can not get the event target if I call it with trigger()?

I got this HTML:

```
<span class="test_span" onmouseover="Test()">
    test
</span>
```

and this JQuery code:

```
function Test() {
    var target = window.event.target || window.event.srcElement;
    console.log(target);
}
$(".test_span").trigger('mouseover');
```

If run it I will get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

but if I hover of the element with the mouse it will return:

```
<span class="test_span" onmouseover="Test()">
    test
</span>
```

How can I solve this? I need to simulate the click with the trigger and get the object. 
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/36rx39t5/)

Comment: `window.event` is MSIE. Use `var evt = e || window.event;` and pass in the event object using `onmouseover="Test(event)">`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/36rx39t5/3/ Don't use `inline handlers`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('.span_width').on('mouseover', function(e) {
    var target = e.target || window.event.srcElement;
    console.log(target);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `inline` event handlers. Use `on`.

See comments inline in code.

HTML:

```
<span class="span_width"><!-- Remove onmouseover="Test()" -->
    test
</span>
```

Javascript:

```
// on mouseover of span_width
$('.span_width').on('mouseover', function (e) {
    // Use event object to get target
    console.log(e.target);
}).trigger('mouseover');
// Trigger mouseover event
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/36rx39t5/3/

Comment: Yeah, this is a nice solution. But will not work in my case. The point is that I have multiple objects that will call Test(), the object that will call the Test() is my target. In this case I must allready now that `.span_width` is the one that I want. Do you know how to do that? I can not really have this: `Test(event)`

Comment: @Pierezzz You can use `$('.span_width, myOtherEl, oneMore').on('mouseover', ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".test_span").mouseover(function(){
    var target = window.event.target || window.event.srcElement;    
    alert(target);
});
```

You can try this, this will be simple to use